# update last record in sql and vb.net using tableAdapter

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have that table:     exitAndEnter
and the columns     id,     exitHour

and i want to do something like this:

```
    update exitAndEnter
    set  exitHour=?
    where id=? AND (exitHour=LAST(exitHour) from enterAndExit)
```

i want     exitHour to be updated only if it's the last record in the requested     id

i hope i explained my self correctly

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the "id" field is autoincremented and "exitHour" will be updated if id is the max() or last record

```
update exitAndEnter
    set  exitHour=?
    where exitHour in(select max(exitHour) from exitAndEnter where id=?)
```

Comment: No, "id" is not autoincremented, it's the id of each user who loggs in the system. I want the app to update only the last record of this user and not all the records (he loggs in and out many times) should i build another column which is autoincremented and work with it ?

Comment: ok i have that one which works in Access but doesn't in VB.NET:           `UPDATE enterAndExit SET exitHour = ? WHERE index in(select max(index)`           `from enterAndExit where id=?);`